# How to sort by day in vb report?

Tags: vb.net, report

I am a vb newbe.  For the past few weeks, i have been developing a hotel reservation system using visual studio and ms access as database for a project.  Everything else is smooth but for a few days, i am having difficulties in filtering my report done using report viewer. Report value is pulled from ms access query. The report is mainly about available guests information sorted by date. In my report,  there is a checkin and checkout date for the guest. So mainly,  the filter should also consider between the checkin n checkout as well. How can i filter my report so that it will show data in descending date order?

Comment: I believe you will have to use the "group and sort" option when in design view > design > grouping & totals

Comment: Is this the one in access? I am only pulling the query from access. I need to filter its report in vb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq or create a view for the datatable and order the datatable and group.

Example of creating the datatable to a view and then sorting:

```
Dim dv As New DataView(oDT)
    dv.Sort ="ColumnName ASC"
    oDT = dv.ToTable
```

Use the ASC for ascending and DESC for descending
The oDT is my datatable that I put into the view to sort

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.The column name like you mentioned will allow me to sort by checkin OR checkout date.But like i said, i have only two values, checkin and checkout. What about the dates between these two dates? Like if checkin is 2 may and checkout is 4 may, how to see the guest record on 3rd may?

Comment: So you want to select the date May 3rd and know who is checked in on this date? If that is the case, what I would do is have a Checked In Date, Checked Out date and those are the two columns, but on your search, make it so the users have to option to select Date checking In, Date Checking Out, and then another option to do a generalized search that checks for all dates rooms are not available. To do this I would just put in a SQL query or Linq query on the datatable. that will filter to the results based on a range that would be the DateCheckedIn to the DateCheckedOut